# Method with generic return

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters

I'm having difficulty writing a method with generic return value.  I'd like to have method that when invoked with a `MachineMorphology` instance return an instance of type `M`, where `M` is the `MachineMorphology` generic type.

Is this possible to accomplish?

MachineMorphology.java

```
public interface MachineMorphology<M extends Machine> {

    Class<? extends M> getClazz();
}
```

ExtrusionMachinesMorphology.java

```
public final class ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<M extends Machine> implements MachineMorphology<M> {
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Doser> DOSER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Doser.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Extruder> EXTRUDER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Extruder.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Blower> BLOWER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Blower.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Die> DIE = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Die.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<HaulOff> HAULOFF = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(HaulOff.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Winder> WINDER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Winder.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<FilmMeasurer> MEASUSER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(FilmMeasurer.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<AirRing> AIR_RING = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(AirRing.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology GEC = null;
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology UNDEFINED = null;

    private final Class<M> clazz;

    public ExtrusionMachinesMorphology(Class<M> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends M> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

AbstractExtrusionPlant.java

```
public abstract class AbstractPlant<T extends PlantType, S extends PlantStatus, O extends PlantOperatorStatus, A extends Alarm> 
    extends ListenableObject<AlarmsListener<Machine, A>> {

    [...]

    private volatile HashMap<MachineMorphology, List<? extends Machine>> machines = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> M getMachine(MachineMorphology<M> morphology, int unitId) {
        return getMachineByUnitId(getMachinesByMorphology(morphology), unitId);
    }

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> M getMachineByUnitId(List<M> machines, int unitId) {
        return machines.stream().filter(machine -> machine.getUnitId() == unitId).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> List<M> getMachinesByMorphology(MachineMorphology<M> morphology) {
        return (List<M>) machines.get(morphology);
    }

    [...]
}
```

This should be the use of the method

```
Doser doser = plant.getMachine(ExtrusionMachinesMorphology.DOSER, 1);
```

But the compiler wants:

```
 Doser doser = (Doser)plant.getMachine(ExtrusionMachinesMorphology.DOSER, 1);
```

Comment: I think that Factory patter is not suitable for my case, because i need to have a class with a list of generic machine(Ordered by MachineMorphology with a HashMap), so when i call the getter i need to specify morphology and unitId(like index) to have the machine instance casted

Comment: If you've got a solution to your question, feel encouraged to add it as an answer.  Don't use "Solved" in your title to indicate that you have a solution; accepting the answer is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking whether it’s possible for a Map to return objects with different generic types.  The answer is no, it is not possible, but you can use the Morphology’s type to convert the List before returning it:

```
public synchronized <M extends Machine> List<M> getMachinesByMorphology(MachineMorphology<M> morphology) {
    Class<? extends M> machineType = morphology.getClazz();
    return machines.get(morphology).stream().map(machineType::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Update**: Here’s the complete file I used for testing compilability:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Machine {
    int getUnitId() { return 0; }
}

class PlantType { }
class PlantStatus { }
class PlantOperatorStatus { }
class Alarm { }
class Doser extends Machine { }
class Extruder extends Machine { }
class Blower extends Machine { }
class Die extends Machine { }
class HaulOff extends Machine { }
class Winder extends Machine { }
class FilmMeasurer extends Machine { }
class AirRing extends Machine { }

interface AlarmsListener<M, A> { }
class ListenableObject<T> { }

interface MachineMorphology<M extends Machine> {

    Class<? extends M> getClazz();
}

final class ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<M extends Machine> implements MachineMorphology<M> {
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Doser> DOSER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Doser.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Extruder> EXTRUDER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Extruder.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Blower> BLOWER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Blower.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Die> DIE = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Die.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<HaulOff> HAULOFF = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(HaulOff.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<Winder> WINDER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(Winder.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<FilmMeasurer> MEASUSER = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(FilmMeasurer.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<AirRing> AIR_RING = new ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<>(AirRing.class);
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<?> GEC = null;
    public static final ExtrusionMachinesMorphology<?> UNDEFINED = null;

    private final Class<M> clazz;

    public ExtrusionMachinesMorphology(Class<M> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends M> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractPlant<T extends PlantType, S extends PlantStatus, O extends PlantOperatorStatus, A extends Alarm> 
    extends ListenableObject<AlarmsListener<Machine, A>> {

    private volatile HashMap<MachineMorphology<? extends Machine>, List<? extends Machine>> machines = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> M getMachine(MachineMorphology<M> morphology,
                                                         int unitId) {
        return getMachineByUnitId(getMachinesByMorphology(morphology), unitId);
    }

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> M getMachineByUnitId(List<M> machines, int unitId) {
        return machines.stream().filter(machine -> machine.getUnitId() == unitId).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public synchronized <M extends Machine> List<M> getMachinesByMorphology(MachineMorphology<M> morphology) {
        Class<? extends M> machineType = morphology.getClazz();
        return machines.get(morphology).stream().map(machineType::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractPlant<PlantType, PlantStatus, PlantOperatorStatus, Alarm> plant =
            new AbstractPlant<PlantType, PlantStatus, PlantOperatorStatus, Alarm>() { };

        Doser doser = plant.getMachine(ExtrusionMachinesMorphology.DOSER, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any advice to have method that return casted machine instance by morphology and unitId ? 

Like my example:
`Doser doser = plant.getMachine(ExtrusionPlantMachinesMorphology.DOSER, 1);`

Comment: I was able to compile the line `Doser doser = plant.getMachine(ExtrusionMachinesMorphology.DOSER, 1);` successfully.  However, I used the class in your question, which is named `ExtrusionMachinesMorphology`, not `ExtrusionPlantMachinesMorphology`, so I’m not sure if I have achieved your goal.

Comment: ExtrusionPlantMachinesMorphology is the old name of the class, it's a copy/paste error
Can you see me your test code?

Comment: Updated answer with full test file.

Comment: Thanks !! i resolved! I instantiated the class without other generics...
Like: AbstractPlant plant = new AbstractPlant(){..};

Comment: That will generate a "raw types" warning from the compiler, and rightly so.  I recommend giving the AbstractPlant instance the types it requires, if at all possible.